# Put if else in array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to put some code in a Javascript array, but it has a condition inside of it:

```
colModel : [

    {display: 'No ', name : 'id_progress'},

    {display: 'Progress Kerja', name : 'progress_kerja'},

    if(admin=='Ya')

    {

        {display: 'Bidang', name : 'nama_bidang'},

    }

    {display: 'Oleh', name : 'nama'},

    {display: 'Tanggal Input', name : 'tanggal_input'}
    ]
```

I can't put an `if` condition in an array literal, any solution for this?

Comment: Yes, you can't do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a function like:

```
colModel: (function(){  
  var arr = [
    {display: 'No ', name : 'id_progress'},
    {display: 'Progress Kerja', name : 'progress_kerja'}
  ];

  admin === 'Ya' && arr.push({display: 'Bidang', name : 'nama_bidang'});

  arr.push(
    {display: 'Oleh', name : 'nama'},
    {display: 'Tanggal Input', name : 'tanggal_input'});

  return arr;
}())
```